# Determine if starting digits of a number repeat later in the same number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

I came across the problem, where I'd like to determine if the number is of the form
$$x=\overline{d_md_{m-1}...d_2d_1d_Md_{M-1}...d_2d_1}$$ in some chosen base, where $d_i$ present a single digit.
This representation effectively means that the first $m$ digits is the same as the last $m$ digits. We can assume that $M \geq m$ so the starting digits does not overlap with the ending digits. Beside that, I do not have any information about $m$ or $M$.

Now, the question is, can I efficiently determine if the number is of this form or not? The base is chosen upfront, so the question is not for a general base. And I do not actually have to find out what $m$ is, I'm just interested if the number is of the desired form. Furthermore, I will be happy already with the some probabilistic approach, where result is given with a high probability.

### What I have thought of so far

What id written below is done for special case where the chosen number base is 10

#### Special case $m=M$

Then we can write

$$x=\overline{d_Md_{M-1}...d_2d_1d_Md_{M-1}...d_2d_1} = \overline{d_Md_{M-1}...d_2d_1}(10^M+1)$$
The number of digits in the representation is $2M$ (can be calculated easiliy) and then I check if $x=0\mod{(10^M+1)}$

#### General case

I can similarly write

$$x=\overline{d_md_{m-1}...d_2d_1d_Md_{M-1}...d_2d_1}=\overline{d_md_{m-1}...d_2d_1}(10^M+1)+\overline{d_Md_{M-1}...d_{m+2}d_{m+1}}10^m$$
Problem here is that I do not know anything about $m$ or $M$.

What I can do is that I calculate first $l$ digits. I had an idea if I can somehow prove that the same sequence can be observed in the number $x-\overline{d_md_{m-1}...d_{m-l+1}}10^{m-l+M}$, I would be on the right track. I $l$ is big enough I can be pretty confident the number is of the desired form.
But I just could not find a way. Maybe some homomorphism can help here, I don't know.

These are just my thoughts, if you can direct me to some other approach, I'm happy to look into it.

Comment: Sort the digits and see if the number of each is divisible by a factor of the length of the number ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee can you please elaborate, what do you mean? I suggest that you use 123412 as an example. I don't understand how your idea should work.

Comment: That sorted is 112234. Now both 1 and 2 divide 6, but they aren't the same so it's not a full repeater ...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee thanks, but actually my goal is to distinguish between these two cases:
a) the beginning of the number repeats at the end (it can be only the first $n$ digits, not necessarily half of all digits) and b) the beginning does not repeat at the end.  
For example, the number 123412 is from the case "a", while the numbers 12344321, 13322414, 45267132 are from the case "b".
I believe your approach would work only if I somehow knew that number is repeating and wanted to know if it is full repeater or not. But in that case, I could use $\mod{10^(M/2)+1$ to test if it is full repeater.